# Integral representation of product of two Whittaker functions

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

Does anyone know anything about the following formula involving special functions:
$$\begin{multline*}
W_{\kappa,\mu}(z)W_{\lambda,\mu}(w)=\frac{e^{-(z+w)/2}(zw)^{\mu+1/2}}{\Gamma(1-\kappa-\lambda)}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{-\kappa-\lambda}(z+t)^{\kappa-\mu-1/2}(w+t)^{\lambda-\mu-1/2} \\
\qquad \qquad \times {}_2F_1\left(\mu-\kappa+1/2,\mu-\lambda+1/2,1-\kappa-\lambda;\frac{t(z+w+t)}{(z+t)(w+t)}\right)\mathrm{d} t \ .\\
\text{for }\qquad \mathrm{Re}(\kappa+\lambda)<1\ ,\qquad z,w\neq 0\ .
\end{multline*}$$
This formula says that the product of two Whittaker functions $W_{\kappa,\mu}$ is equivalent to an integral of a hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1$ against some weight.

I came across this formula on page 74 of [Iwanami mathematical formulas 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/4000055097) (written in Japanese). You can also find this in equation 7.526.3 of [Table of Integrals, Series, and Products](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780123849335/table-of-integrals-series-and-products), on page 401 of [Tables of Integral Transforms volume 2](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/), and in equation 6.15.3.21 in [higher transcendental functions. vol. i](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwigqtLt4rPsAhXxw4sBHSy_DLAQFjABegQIAxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.nrbook.com%2Fbateman%2FVol1.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3SRHY8rTg2r-ckNgeVpvLA)  But I could not find the original paper where this formula is derived. Could you tell me any reference books for this formula?

Answer (score 6):

I finally found [the right paper written by A. Erdélyi](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14786443808562178) in which the formula is introduced. They derived this formula by writing Whittaker functions as Laplace type integral forms and using convolutional properties of Laplace transformation.